# Avoid version specific information in configSection in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config, config

I have made a small GUI for administration of some settings in an app.config file. The GUI is released as part of my product, making it possible to change values in the app.config file, without opening this in a text editor.

The properties are implemented in a custom configSection, making it strongly typed in the code. My problem is, that when the app.config file is updated (when I save from the GUI), the fully qualified name of my assembly is written in the configSection like this:

```
<section name="ConfigurationSettings" type="PerformanceDude.MSBuildShellExtension.Common.ConfigurationSettings, Common, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1ab1b15115e63xxx" />
```

When I upgrade this assembly to a new version number, the GUI code assembly version not longer matches the assembly references in the app.config.

This is how I load the settings:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = ConfigFilePath }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var settings = Config.GetSection("ConfigurationSettings") as ConfigurationSettings;
```

This is how I save the settings:

```
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal, true);
```

I don't want to write an upgrade script changing the version everytime I update. Does anyone know a great solution to this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to include the code you use to serialize and save the config please?

Comment: The load and save code is now in the description :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Can't remember. Don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do a similar thing before.  I ended up loading the config file as xml, de-serializing the relevant sections into objects, then putting them back into the xml.  Avoiding the .net configuration API in that way avoid issues with the version.

Another approach is to redirect the old version of the assembly to a new version.  If your assembly is in the GAC, you can use policy files to do this, and deploy them when you deploy a new version; then the version numbers in the config won't matter.

Comment: Actually --- if you add the configuration DLL to the GAC then you do not need a fully qualified name when defining your configuration section.  All you need is (class, assembly)

Comment: Sure @SASS_Shooter, but the point is that he does not need to care if something puts the version number in there if he has a policy file.

Comment: The DLL is not in the GAC. If I load the config as XML, the data wouldn't be strongly typed i C#. The whole idea with using a config section was for me to be able to load and save each property through a C# object containing strongly typed properties. Thank you for your proposal, though :)